# I can't decode data from HTML page in swift

Tags: html, swift, decode, nsurlsession

I am trying to decode data from an HTML page to be readable but the `urlContent` String is nil even though `data` returned from the `NSURlSession` is non-nil.

My implementation:

```
var city = "London" 
var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=weather+in+" + city.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+"))

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data , response, error) -> Void in
                var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!
                println(urlContent)
})
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are you getting an error?  Do you have a programming question?

Comment: variable urlContent has nil value instead of html code. that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an optional `NSData` (or "`NSData?`"). You have to unwrap it.

**Update:** I switched to `NSASCIIStringEncoding` (from `NSUTF8StringEncoding`) as Eric D. pointed out. I also updated the code for Swift 2.

This works for me:

```
let city = "London"
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=weather+in+" + city.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+"))

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data , response, error) -> Void in
    if let data = data,
        urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) {
        print(urlContent)
    } else {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
})

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

Aaron Brager's answer would usually work, *but in this specific case*, because of the encoding server-side, you have to decode the HTML with `NSASCIIStringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data , response, error) -> Void in
    if let data = data {
        var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        println(urlContent)
    } else {
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }
})
task.resume()
```